# How to add custom data in controller Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, insert, laravel-6

I have a form that will send data like `title, demo, text`. These fields can be inserted by the user but I have `user_id` in the table that should automatically be inserted by the framework itself. I don't want to create `<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='{{Auth::user()->id}}'>` because it is NOT safe at all. How can I fill up `user_id` automatically when a user has to fill the form?

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //TODO: ADD user_id to this data and insert into tbl
    $v_data = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|min:5',
        'demo' => 'required',
        'text' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);

    Post::create($v_data);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Please show the code in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Post::create($v_data);
```

you can use:

```
Post::create($v_data + ['user_id' => auth()->id()]);
```

Comment: wow .. i didn't know it was just simple array .. thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it..

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
//TODO: ADD user_id to this data and insert into tbl
$v_data=$request->validate([
    'title'=>'required|min:5',
    'demo'=>'required',
    'text'=>'required',
    'category'=>'required|numeric',
]);

$v_data['user_id']=auth()->user()->id;// this extra line

Post::create($v_data);
return redirect()->back();
```

}